# Let $G$ be a group and $H\unlhd G$ such that $[G:H]=20$ and $|H|=7$. Suppose $x\in G$ and $x^7=e$. Show that $x\in H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I'm currently on an exercise problem from Dan Saracino Abstract Algebra, Exercise 11.20. It says the following:

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $[G:H]=20$ and $|H|=7$. Suppose $x\in G$ and $x^7=e$. Show that $x\in H$.

Can I get some help with this, please?

Answer (score 1):

Let $p:G\to G/H$ be the quotient projection, sending each element of $G$ to its coset in $G/H$. Since this is a homomorphism and since $x^7=e$ in $G$, we have $p(x)^7=e$ in $G/H$. But the order of $p(x)$ (or any element) in $G/H$ divides the order of $G/H$, which is 20 and, in particular, is relatively prime to $7$. So $p(x)=e$. That is, $x$ is in the kernel of $p$, which is $H$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $H$ is a normal $G$ subgroup of size $7$ and index $20$. Given $x\in G$ and $x^7=e$ then $$\text{ord}(x\cdot H)=1\;\;\text{OR}\;\;\text{ord}(x\cdot H)=7$$ The former implies $x\in H$ but from Lagrange's theorem the latter implies $7\;\vert\;|\frac{G}{H}|$ or equivalently $7\;\vert\;20$ which is false. $\;\;\;\;\therefore\forall x\in G\;x^7=e\implies x\in H$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $G=7 \times 20$ so $H$ is the $7$-Sylow subgroup of $G$. Since $H$ is normal, $H$ it is the unique $7$-Sylow subgroup of $G$. Therefore, it must contain all elements of order $7$.